# Inter-Image communication in Smalltalk. Possible?

Tags: smalltalk, concurrency, squeak

I have a graph-traversal problem that is beautifully and elegantly modeled in smalltalk, but it's too big (in terms of computation and storage) for one smalltalk image instance. So, I want to partition the problem across multiple instances.

My question is, is there any good way to send messages between smalltalk instances. Kind of like MPI, but for smalltalk.

I should mention that I'm on Squeak, but if there is some flavor of smalltalk with this feature, I can cope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project named Hydra underway, with a goal to make a Squeak multi-core capable. One of the main features of Hydra are also the inter-image communication channels.

Some more information:

- [Qwaq releases Hydra multi-core Squeak VM](http://news.squeak.org/2008/02/21/qwaq-releases-hydra-multi-core-squeak-vm/)
- [HydraVM devnotes](http://squeakvm.org/~sig/hydravm/devnotes.html)
- [[squeak-dev] [ANN] Hydra now can do mitosis](http://www.nabble.com/-squeak-dev---ANN--Hydra-now-can-do-mitosis-td22146618.html)

Comment: In the meantime try to make your own TCP/IP channels for communication. It is a bit hard to start, but later you can achieve quite a flexible communication.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Remote Smalltalk](http://www.squeaksource.com/rST.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Open Croquet](http://www.opencroquet.org/) is conceptually a bunch of Smalltalk images communicating with each other. Maybe it, and its Islands, might be a good fit?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I dare to mention OpenTalk library from  Cincom VisualWorks. OpenTalk main advantage is that in many cases you just put it in and the rest of your code just works across the network. Its basic idea is to replace remote object with local proxy and send messages to a image.

VisualWorks page at Cincom: http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/products/visualworks

Answer (score 1):

At Esug2012, Nick Papoulias showed [Seamless](http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/Seamless.html). It is part of the effort in Pharo to separate the environment where the tools run from the development image.